# Using Extract Method Action from a plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, automated-refactoring, extract-method

I'm just starting out developing eclipse plugins so forgive me if this is an easy question, but I am developing a plugin in which the first step consists of analysing the source code of a Java application and Extract new Methods.

My plugin determines the sequence of statements  to be extracted. I want to use **ExtractMethodAction** (http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fui%2Factions%2Fpackage-summary.html).

Note that, my plugin recover a sequence of statements (http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2Fdom%2FStatement.html) and not an **ITextSelection** which is the parameter of the method **run** of the class **ExtractMethodAction**. Moreover, the constructor of **ExtractMethodAction** has as a parameter **JavaEditor** and I do not know how to create a **JavaEditor** for an **ICompilationUnit**.

This is a part of the method **execute** of my plugin:

```
public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {


    IWorkspace workspace= ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
    IWorkspaceRoot root = workspace.getRoot();

    IProject [] projects = root.getProjects();
    for(IProject project: projects){


        IJavaProject javaProject = JavaCore.create(project); 
        try {

            IPackageFragment [] packages =javaProject.getPackageFragments();

            for (IPackageFragment mypackage: packages){


                if (mypackage.getKind() == IPackageFragmentRoot.K_SOURCE){


                    ICompilationUnit[] units =  mypackage.getCompilationUnits();
                    for (ICompilationUnit unit: units){

                        Parser myparser = new Parser();
                        CompilationUnit cu=  myparser.parse(unit);
                        ...

                    }   

                }           
           }
```

and this is how I tried to use ExtractMethodAction:

```
JavaEditor edit;
ExtractMethodAction act= new ExtractMethodAction(edit);
ITextSelection select;
act.run(select);
```

Note that I did not know how to initialise  the **JavaEditor** and  the   **ITextSelection** .

Can you help me please to use **ExtractMethodAction** if possible or tell me if it would be better to devellope my own code. Thank you very much.

Comment: `JavaEditor` is an open Java text editor, `ExtractMethodAction` looks like it will only work with the Java editor open.

Comment: So unless all the classes I want to analyse are opened, I can not use ExtractMethodAction.